# Add git remote to local source

Tags: git

I have a local directory that contains the source code, minus the `.git` folder, so it has no git integration. I want to add the remote and pull down any changes. I tried `git init && git remote add origin https://...`, however it wants me to make an initial commit. As there is an existing project, I don't want to make an initial commit.

How can I add the remote repo remote and pull down changes without an initial commit?

Comment: [First google result.](http://www.thehorrors.org.uk/snippets/git-local-filesystem-remotes/) Does it work?

Comment: I think that an easier approach would be to do it in the opposite order.
First clone the remote repository to have a local copy *with* it's `.git` folder, then copy your changes into the existing repository.

Answer (score 2):

Easier would be:

```
git clone /url/remote/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/source add .
git commit -m "update repo with local source"
git push
```

The trick is using the `git --work-tree=<path>` option in order to add files which are not in the current local repo worktree.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. However, to answer your question, you cannot, at least not without cloning/forking. If you just adding your code to an already existing repo, and you are a collaborator of said repo, you can branch the repo, add your code, and pull request for the owner to merge your branch into the master.

If you are the only dev on the project your init commit and subsequent push simply add the project to server, and thus start the git magic of version control.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to add the remote and pull down any changes.

You can turn the local directory into a Git repository, add the remote, and fetch its content.

```
git init
git remote add origin repo-url
git fetch origin master
```

When you say "pull down any changes",
it seems to suggest that you don't have local changes,
you just want to be up to date with the remote repo.
If that's the case, you can hard-reset the local repo to the remote,
discarding any local differences:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

As a result, the local directory will be up to date with the remote repo,
*and* it will be a proper Git repo with a `.git` directory.

Comment: You can't run git commands in a folder that is not initiated as a git repo. The OP states that his code resides in a location without a `.git` folder.

Comment: @Lix I understood the question that he already did `git init`. Maybe I misunderstood. I clarified that point now.